# Chrome native app install banner not working

Tags: android, json, google-chrome, manifest

I am trying to enable showing native app install banner for my client site using documentation https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/03/increasing-engagement-with-app-install-banners-in-chrome-for-android.

The error I see is `App banner not shown: manifest could not be fetched, is empty, or could not be parsed`

Below is my `manifest.json`

```
{
  "name": "PayPal",
  "short_name": "PayPal",
  "start_url": "https://www.paypal.com/webapps/mpp/home",
  "display": "standalone",
  "icons": [{
    "src": "https://www.paypalobjects.com/digitalassets/c/website/logo/monogram/pp_fc_mg.png",
    "sizes": "48x48",
    "type": "image/png"
  }, {
    "src": "https://www.paypalobjects.com/digitalassets/c/website/logo/monogram/pp_fc_mg_2x.png",
    "sizes": "96x96",
    "type": "image/png"
  }, {
    "src": "https://www.paypalobjects.com/digitalassets/c/website/logo/monogram/pp_fc_mg_2x.png",
    "sizes": "144x144",
    "type": "image/png"
  }],
  "prefer_related_applications": true,
  "related_applications": [{
    "platform": "play",
    "id": "com.paypal.android.p2pmobile"
  }]
}
```

Looking at the n/w console, `manifest.json` is fetched. Seeing the server 200 response. Its not empty and a valid JSON.

Can some help me point the issue. Thanks.

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: Did some digging around and realized there is no good native solution that commonly works across iOS & Android. So ended up creating by own custom component for it.